# Design vision error OPT-1206 AFTER VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am facing an problem in design vision like definition is:

"The register THRESHOLD is constant and will be removed"

Since I declared a signal and I initialized to some value to make it constant.  I want these constant values for some comparison purposes ....what to DO next??

```
begin
P :  PROCESS(CLK,RST)
VARIABLE THRESHOLD: signed(10 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
IF(RST='1')THEN   -- RESET CONDITION
THRESHOLD:="00011111111";
ELSIF(RISING_EDGE(CLK))THEN

H1<=(SIGNED("000"&P2)+SIGNED("00"&P3(7 DOWNTO 0)&'0')+SIGNED("000"&P6))-(SIGNED("000"&P4)+SIGNED("00"&P7(7 DOWNTO 0)&'0')+SIGNED("000"&P8));
IF(H1>=THRESHOLD) THEN
MAG_DL<="11111111";
ELSE

 IF H1(10)='0' THEN
  MAG_DL<=H1(7)&H1(6)&H1(5)&H1(4)&H1(3)&H1(2)&H1(1)&H1(0);
  ELSE
  H2<=NOT (H1(10)&H1(9)&H1(8)&H1(7)&H1(6)&H1(5)&H1(4)&H1(3)&H1(2)&H1(1)&H1(0));
  H2<=H2+("00000000001");
  IF(H2 >="11111111") THEN
  MAG_DL<="11111111";
  ELSE
  MAG_DL<=H2(7)&H2(6)&H2(5)&H2(4)&H2(3)&H2(2)&H2(1)&H2(0);
  END IF;
  END IF;
```

Comment: If you want a constant, don't declare a signal or a variable : declare a constant!

Comment: in this program "threshold" ;i want it to be constant...and also its a signed number...but h1>="00011111111" its creats error in simulation...

Comment: `constant THRESHOLD: signed(10 DOWNTO 0) := "00011111111";`

Answer (score 0):

Variables are supposed to vary.  Yours doesn't change, so the compiler notices that and very nicely optimises it for you - and lets you know.

Constants do not vary - the compiler won't even let you try and change them.  So if you want a constant value, tell the compiler that's your intention:

```
constant THRESHOLD : signed (10 downto 0) := "some value";
```